# Dynamic HexClock Program

Tags: java, javafx, hex, clock

I feel like i want to practicing Java in a more Object-Oriented way, that it is supposed.

I am doing a small hobby project that i got inspiration from a android app called HexaTime.

The idea or the end result I'm aiming for is the follow scenario:

Opens the application, 
A digital clock is showing with a hexalike format #093343 instead of the usual 09:33:44 /hh:mm:ss.

The background color of the window itself is to be changed with the exact current time and counting/converting the hour, minute and seconds in to real hexadecimals. Then a color function will change the color of the background taking the hexadecimals and converting it to R,G,B format / or if its possible to put the pure hexadecimals into a Paint.valueOf(); ?

At the beginning i thought i could be simple, but now that i have tried a bit i realize its possible, but take a bit more time and a bit more complex than i thought.

Would really appreciate some help, for example displaying the clock on the window. 
Here is as far as i have got, i have tried some different approaches with Timer.scheduleFixRate or what it was called but could go forward with it due to lack of further knowledge of how to proceed.

ClockView

```
package hexatime;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClockView extends Application{


    public static void main (String[] args)  throws InterruptedException{
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("HexaClock");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new ClockController(), 450,300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

ClockController

```
package hexatime;

import java.util.Calendar;
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class ClockController extends Label{

    public ClockModel clock;

    public ClockController(){
        //updateTime();
    }

    /*private void updateTime(){
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0),
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    setText(sdf.format(time.getTime()));
                }
            }
        ),
        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1))
        );
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
        }*/

    public static int[] hexToNum(String hex){
        //if (hex.charAt(0) == "#"){
            //hex = hex.split("#");
            hex = hex.toUpperCase();
            String hex_alphabets = "0123456789ABCDEF";
            int[] value = new int[3];
            int k = 0;
            int int1, int2;
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i+=2){
                int1 = hex_alphabets.indexOf(hex.charAt(i));
                int2 = hex_alphabets.indexOf(hex.charAt(i+1));
                value[k] = (int1 * 16) + int2;
                k++;
            }
            return value;
        }
}
```

ClockModel

```
package hexatime;

import java.util.Date;

public class ClockModel implements ClockInterface {

    public int hour;
    public int minute;
    public int seconds;
    public String hexHour;
    public String hexMinute;
    public String hexSecond;


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public ClockModel(Date time){
        hour = time.getHours();
        minute = time.getMinutes();
        seconds= time.getSeconds();
    }

    public int getHour(){
        return hour;
    }

    public int getMinutes(){
        return minute;
    }

    public int getSeconds(){
        return seconds;
    }
```

}

Comment: Hexadecimal numbers use sixteen different digits and a clock showing such digits will only be useful for aliens with sixteen fingers. Or what do you mean by "healike"? Anyway, it's unclear whether you want to represent time as a colour, or by numerals, or both. I can't see any question you are asking here, only the statement that you don't know (yet) what you want to program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot comment about how to go with the OOPs concept, but I can show you how to do this in JavaFX in a simple way.

- You can paint your background directly through the hexcode using css.

> ```
> pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color : your hex code");
> ```

- You can use a `Timeline` instead of `Timer.scheduleFixRate` which will always keep your changes on the JavaFX Application Thread

A simple example to show these things (in one single class, you can later divide them adding more functionalities and apply OOPs to it ;) )

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class HexTime extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(getColoredPane(), 450, 500);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hexa Time");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public BorderPane getColoredPane() {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        Label label = new Label();
        label.setFont(Font.font(20));

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        KeyFrame changeColor = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
                new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                        Map<String, String> colortime = generateColor();
                        label.setText(colortime.get("time"));
                        label.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white");
                        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color : " + colortime.get("color"));
                    }
                });
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(changeColor);
        timeline.play();
        pane.setCenter(label);
        return pane;

    }

    public Map<String, String> generateColor() {

        int hour;
        int min;
        int sec;
        Calendar cal;
        String hexValue;
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        sec = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        // Color Code Production
        hexValue = String.format("%02X%02X%02X", hour, min, sec);
        map.put("color", "#" + hexValue);
        map.put("time", "#" + String.format("%02d", hour) + String.format("%02d", min) + String.format("%02d", sec));
        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Haha thank you. Its exactly as i was aiming for. Unfortnuatly i know i would have take me a long time to even get to a near result. Well i will look at your code and try dividing it and do it by my self. Thanks again :D